# Avoiding lag in displaying complex views with ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

For the development of my app, I realized I needed a complicated view (let's call it `foo`), it contains three `ImageButton`s, a `progress bar`, and three `TextView`s, all of which are dynamically changed by interacting with **the same view's** elements. To make this work, I extended `foo` from `RelativeLayout`, dynamically created the sub-views then added them to `foo` (`this.addView(...)`).

What I planned to do next was add them dynamically to a `ScrollView`. I did this and put three `foo`s for testing. The result was extreme lag. I'd press an `ImageView` (which should change its image on press), and it would take 2 seconds to do so.

My final aim would be to support 50 of these `foo`s at a time and have them work smoothly, with the user having the option of loading more (without overwriting the previous ones) if he/she so chooses. All interactions will use the internet (I dunno if that's relevant), but the testing was done with all the network tasks commented out.

My questions are thus:

1. Is the strategy I was using (`ScrollView` & add `foo`s to them) viable, and the lag is from some other issue (the specific code in question, in which case I'll provide some code)? Or is it really a bad idea to do that?
2. What would be the best way to reach my goal here (assuming 1 is bad)?

---

What I already know:

I've researched my problem a bit, and most online sources recommend using a `ListView`. I didn't read much into it but from what I got:

- I'd have to redo the design using xml rather than dynamically
- The different components and their values will be stored each on it's own array which is **extremely** unacceptable in my situation (changing the sub-view's values should be done very simply and should not appear in the main activity)
- I can't (or it's difficult to) set `OnClickListener`'s for the different sub-views (as only the main `foo` view will get one)

---

I also tried this method (`ScrollView` and add to `Views`) with another `View` and had 20 of them run at the same time seamlessly, but that one had been extended from `View` and only used `canvas` to draw text with no sub-views.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'd have to redo the design using xml rather than dynamically" -- no, you do not. "The different components and their values will be stored each on it's own array" -- you are welcome to create your own `BaseAdapter` subclass that wraps whatever data model you desire. "I can't (or it's difficult to) set OnClickListener's for the different sub-views (as only the main foo view will get one)" -- you call `setOnClickListener()` on the "sub-views", just as you do today. "the lag is from some other issue" -- use Traceview to determine where your problem is.

Comment: In your experience, should adding this many views cause a lag? Or maybe it's because the `OnClickListener` function is in another class? I'll see what I can figure out from Traceview. Thanks

Comment: "should adding this many views cause a lag?" -- it will not be fast, and it will consume a fair bit of heap. However, at the level of "it would take 2 seconds to do so", disk I/O or network I/O almost certainly have to be involved. Perhaps you are doing some things on the main application thread that you should not. Traceview will help with this, as would `StrictMode`.